# last quarter and next quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to get the dates for the last quarter and next quarter.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
convert(date, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,GETDATE()) -1 ,0)) FirstQDate,
convert(date, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q,0,GETDATE()),0))) LastQDate
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check [This](http://zarez.net/?p=2484)

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)-- First day of last quarter
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))-- Last day of last quarter
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)-- First day of Next quarter
SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) +2, 0))-- Last day of Next quarter
```

Comment: I just came into this answer but it looks wrong. it gives me '2018-04-01' if I run select DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, '2018-04-05'), 0), it supposed to give me '2018-03-31'

Answer (score 1):

And, in <strike>many</strike> *most* real-world companies that I've worked at over the years, there is somewhere a "great-big table with hundreds of years' worth of dates in it." Other columns in that table provide the pre-calculated *business numbers* (whatever they might be ...) for each date.

There's a program out there somewhere which is (was ...) used to fill this table, and it's *full* of "calculations like that," precisely so that *no other program or query* has to do the same thing. Instead, they just "look it up."

There are often many identical copies of this table scattered about, and they appear in most of the queries in the business. When the date-related computations of the business are ... *"well, strange"* ... (as they so-often are) ... this happens to be a pragmatic and elegant solution. It pushes "complicated calculations" out of the queries themselves, in favor of these *pre-calculated* numbers.